Invalid parameter 'model' for estimator KerasRegressor
Can you guys tell me where am I going wrong with this implementation? Why am I getting the error: "Invalid parameter 'model' for estimator KerasRegressor" ? I would sincerely appreciate your help.
    from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import datasets
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, KFold
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.optimizers import Adam
  

    diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
    X = diabetes.data
    y = diabetes.target
    
    # Split data into training, validation, and test sets
    X_train_val, X_test, y_train_val, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train_val, y_train_val, test_size=0.125, random_state=1)  # 0.125 x 0.8 = 0.1
    
    # Define a model builder function
    def auto_CreateNeural(optimizer='adam', activation='relu'):
        regressor = Sequential()
        regressor.add(Dense(10, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation=activation))
        regressor.add(Dense(1))
        regressor.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)
    
        return regressor
    
    # Wrap the model with KerasRegressor
    regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn=auto_CreateNeural, verbose=1)
    
    # Define parameters for GridSearchCV
    param_grid = {
        'model__optimizer': ['adam', 'sgd'],
        'model__activation': ['relu', 'tanh'],
        'model__batch_size': [4, 8],
        'model__epochs': [10, 20]
    }
    
    # Setup cross-validation
    kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=regressor, param_grid=param_grid, cv=kf, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', return_train_score=True)
    
    # Perform Grid Search
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_train_val, y_train_val)
    
    # Evaluate the best model on the test set
    best_model = grid.best_estimator_
    test_loss = best_model.score(X_test, y_test)
    
    # Output results
    print("Best GridSearchCV score: {:.2f}".format(grid_result.best_score_))
    print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_result.best_params_))
    print("Test set loss: {:.2f}".format(test_loss))
    
    # Optionally, check how it performs on the validation set if needed
    validation_loss = best_model.score(X_val, y_val)
    print("Validation set loss: {:.2f}".format(validation_loss))

Error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[48\], line 43
40 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=regressor, param_grid=param_grid, cv=kf, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', return_train_score=True)
42 # Perform Grid Search
\---\> 43 grid_result = grid.fit(X_train_val, y_train_val)
45 # Evaluate the best model on the test set
46 best_model = grid.best_estimator\_

 ValueError: Invalid parameter 'model' for estimator KerasRegressor(
build_fn=<function auto_CreateNeural at 0x71a81c62f600>

This code works perfectly in the tensorflow keras wrapper for Keras Regressor, but not scikeras.

Since the diabetes dataset is intended for binary classification, you should
be using KerasClassifier instead of KerasRegressor, which is used for
regression tasks.
